# Result of Infinite Sum of Rational Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, rational-functions

I am trying to understand how this infinite sum is calculated:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k+2}-\frac{1}{4k+4}$$

I tried some common techniques but I can't find a way to prove what this converges into, which is $\frac{ln(2)}{2}$. I tried converting into an integral to calculate but I didn't get far, same with Fourier series. Is there a known way to solve this?

Comment: If you multiply with $2$ , you should see the pattern of the sum easier and why the resulting sum converges to $\ln(2)$.

Comment: @Riccardo Do you know what a "telescoping sum" is?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If we rewrite the series as
$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2 k + 1} - \frac{1}{2 k + 2}\right),$$
we can see that expanding gives
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots\right) .$$
Can you identify the series here as the value of a well-known Taylor series at some point?